# Rubocop command not found in ruby 3.0.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I am trying to run rubocop on ruby 3.0.3 console

```
 rubocop
```

and I am getting the following.

```
rbenv: rubocop: command not found

The `rubocop' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.3.3
  2.5.1
  2.5.3
  2.6.5
  2.7.0
```

Comment: Unless you change to one of the listed Ruby versions, you'll have to install it in the one you're currently using now. It doesn't work in the way that one gem is installed for one Ruby version and can be used in another one.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use RuboCop as a "naked" command from anywhere, you need to install it in your system gems:

```
gem install rubocop
```

Ruby needs to install the gems for each Ruby version independently.

If you are using bundler, and in a project that has RuboCop installed from its Gemfile, you can invoke that particular version using bundler:

```
bundle exec rubocop
```